# Javascript function not executing onsubmit

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble executing a function on form submit. When I test by calling a simple `alert()` function using the `onclick` event it works fine `onclick="alert('hi')"` but when I change the event to `onsubmit="alert('hi')"` it does not call the function? Can anyone tell me why? How do I fix it?

```html
<form role="form" id="theForm" name="myForm" method="POST" action="processApplication.cfm">
      
        <fieldset id="personal">
          <legend>Personal</legend>
           
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
              <label for="cfnm" class="control-label form-adjust">First Name*</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cfnm" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="" maxlength="30"><i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
              <label for="cmnm" class="control-label form-adjust">Middle Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cmnm" name="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name" value="" maxlength="30">
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
              <label for="clnm" class="control-label form-adjust">Last Name*</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clnm" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="" maxlength="40"><i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
              <label for="ceml" class="control-label form-adjust">Email*</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ceml" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="" maxlength="128"><i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
              <label for="czip" class="control-label form-adjust">Personal URL</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="curl" name="url" placeholder="Personal URL" value="" maxlength="10">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
    
        <fieldset>               
          <div class="form-group row">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                  
                  <input id="sbtn" name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary form-adjust" onsubmit="alert('hi');">
              </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        
    </form>
```

Comment: `onSubmit` function should be on `<form />` element not `<input />` element I believe.

Comment: I think this is cold fusion, isn't it? and where the javascript code?

Comment: Doh! That's it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onsubmit is a attribute for the form so try change it to

```
<form role="form" id="theForm" name="myForm" method="POST" action="processApplication.cfm" onsubmit="alert('hi');">

    <fieldset id="personal">
      <legend>Personal</legend>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
          <label for="cfnm" class="control-label form-adjust">First Name*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cfnm" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value="" maxlength="30"><i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
          <label for="cmnm" class="control-label form-adjust">Middle Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cmnm" name="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name" value="" maxlength="30">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
          <label for="clnm" class="control-label form-adjust">Last Name*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="clnm" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value="" maxlength="40"><i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
          <label for="ceml" class="control-label form-adjust">Email*</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ceml" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="" maxlength="128"><i class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><span></span></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 text-nowrap">
          <label for="czip" class="control-label form-adjust">Personal URL</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 form-adjust">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="curl" name="url" placeholder="Personal URL" value="" maxlength="10">
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>               
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">

              <input id="sbtn" name="submit_button" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary form-adjust">
          </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```